# Intuituive reason why Fermats last theorem holds

Tags: number-theory, intuition

I am unsure of whether it is normal, but to me, intuitively Fermats last theorem should not hold.

If anyone intuitively believed it to be correct, why?

> Can someone explain so I understand somewhat why FLT holds without reading a massive and complex proof?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I imagine that if there were some intuitive reason, the theorem wouldn't require a massive and complex proof.

Comment: The intuition is that higher powers of integers get so rare that none of them are the sum of two others.

Comment: Just because a result has an intuitive explanation does *not* mean you should expect a simple proof.  Faltings's theorem (the Mordell conjecture) has an intuitive explanation by embedding a curve of genus at least $2$ into its Jacobian and using the Mordell-Weil theorem for abelian varieties over number fields (the curve has dimension $1$ but its Jacobian has dimension $g \geq 2$), but nobody has succeeded in turning this idea into a simple proof of Faltings's theorem.

Comment: @KCd Even worse : Weil himself, and Serre also, had the intuition that Weil's conjecture should be proven by the use of a cohomology theory. They were right, but we waited for Grothendieck, and Deligne (and many others in between) to give a firm basis to this "intuition". ;-)

Comment: @DisplayName: Can you explain your intuition for why you think FLT should not hold?  Specifically, are you saying your intution tells you there should be *some* counterexample for *some* $n$ or that there should be *some* counterexample for infinitely many $n$?

Comment: Example 2 on https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/the-probabilistic-heuristic-justification-of-the-abc-conjecture/ gives a probabilistic heuristic for why any particular Fermat equation in degree greater than 3 (hence not really treating the case of exponent 3) should have at most finitely many solutions. I have never seen a probabilistic heuristic that suggests a Fermat equation of degree greater than 2 should have no nontrivial solutions, only at most finitely many integer solutions (up to scaling).

Comment: @DisplayName: Your intuition is really unsatisfactory. Consider the equation $2a = 2b + 1$ as $a$ and $b$ run over the integers: there are infinitely many choices for $a$ and for $b$, so "surely" there should be an integer solution?!?!

Comment: Another discussion of probabilistic heuristics behind the unlikelihood of integer solutions, especially if we grant it as known that FLT is true from exponent 3 up into the millions by other methods already, is on the slides http://www.math.uci.edu/~krubin/lectures/psbreakfast.pdf.

Comment: But "compatible" to one person could be "incompatible" to someone else with more experience. Consider $x^2 - 3y^2 = 2$. There are tons of real solutions, so therefore would you say there should be an integer solution "intuitively" if you don't grant any knowledge of number theory? That equation reduces mod $3$ to $x^2 \equiv 2 \bmod 3$, which has no solution, so the original equation has no integer solution. Would you say $x^2 - 3y^2 = 2$ "seems compatible" if you don't allow the use of modular arithmetic to check obstructions?

Comment: Maybe your idea of "compatible" is that there is no congruence obstruction to solvability. That is, if a polynomial equation $f(x,y) = 0$ or $f(x,y,z) = 0$ has solutions mod $m$ for all $m \geq 2$ do you feel that "intuitively" it should have an integer solution? While appealing, this idea in general is just flat out *false*. For example, if $k$ is a nonzero integer then the congruence $y^2 \equiv x^3 + k \bmod m$ is solvable in $x$ and $y$ for each integer $m \geq 2$, but the equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$ need not have any integer solutions. For instance, $y^2 = x^3 - 5$ has no integer solutions.

Comment: @DisplayName: Please tell us what you mean for an equation to be "compatible."

Comment: @KCd Compatible(already stated as baseless) to me, means that there are many varied near hits. So having a variety of close to solutions of varied distances, it seems likely that if we consider an infinite number of cases, one should break FLT

Comment: Solving the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ yields a product of *n* coprime quantities equaling a product of two quantities, of which one is a prime power. This creates problems $($conflicts$)$ for any number other than $2$. But *proving* that this is *always* the case is a completely different matter altogether.

Comment: The number of comments here generated a system flag. I deleted a bunch in response. Partly because comments were becoming a bit too personal and partly because they had no mathematical content. Display Name, I will not rule whether your question is appropriate, but it is a bit vague. Possibly because *intuition* is subjective, and develops when a person studies a field. Have you considered editing the question, and including the source of your intuition. No need to be shy, if you think it is low level. This would clarify the question and give the answerers something to build on.

Answer (score 2):

You will find a lot of intuitive reasons why Fermat last theorem holds in the following book : "[Modular Forms and Fermat’s Last Theorem](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-0-387-98998-3)", from Cornell, Silverman and Joseph, I quite liked it in my young years.