# Is there an intuitive explanation for Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: number-theory

Does a heuristic explanation exist why $x^n+y^n=z^n \;\forall x,y,n,z\in \mathbb{Z},n>2$ doesn't have any solutions?

I'm not asking for an elementary proof or for an explanation of Wile's proof but maybe there is some kind of intuitive reasoning why the proposition should be true. Why did Fermat and many other mathematicians think that it was true? Did they just try a lot of different values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuituive reason why Fermats last theorem holds](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124346/intuituive-reason-why-fermats-last-theorem-holds)

Comment: There are certainly elementary proofs of FLT for small $n$, like 3, 4 and maybe 5, I can't remember. I always figured Fermat probably had a proof for small $n$ that failed to generalize for some subtle reason which he didn't immediately notice.

Comment: Fermat thought he had a proof. The driving reason for early exploration was likely as much because they trusted Fermat's note that he had a proof, rather than heuristics.

Comment: But recall that, based on just the example of $n=2$ and $n=6$, and the lack of examples, it was long conjectured that there were no orthogonal latin $n\times n$ squares when $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$. This was because (1) it was easy to handle the other cases of $n\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ and (2) the  two small cases could be shown to not exist. Turns out, the conjecture was wrong for all other $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$...

Comment: There's a heuristic argument suggesting that there are finitely many solutions for fixed $n$ (which can be proven using Faltings' theorem), and an argument suggesting that there are finitely many solutions overall using the abc conjecture, but I'm not aware of a heuristic argument for strengthening "finitely many" to "none."

Comment: Probably just asked whether the exponent in the Pythogoras formula could be larger than 2, with natural number solutions, and found no small solutions.. The case n=4 is elementary. Cases n=3 and n=5 were, if I recall correctly, solved by Euler. It was later shown to hold if n is a regular prime (a certain kind of prime, of which there are infinitely many).  Fermat sometimes announced results without revealing proofs. I dk whether he announced this one or just made the famous written marginal note.

Comment: Also every other announced result of Fermat was eventually solved by others,  so it was suspected that he had had a proof. The feeling today is generally that he made a mistake, but not  a trivial one.

Comment: Surely, an elementary proof for the case $n=3$ has been posted in this forum. Can anyone establish a link to it ?

Comment: @user254665 Even Fermat was a human being that can have made an elementary error. If I am informed right, he claimed that he has found an easy proof. This is very unlikely because it took very long until a proof was found. But who knows, perhaps Fermat found a very difficult proof which seemed easy to him ...

Comment: Ironical his conjecture that every number of the form $2^{2^n}+1$ is prime. Today, there are good reasons to believe that there is no Fermat-prime besides the primes Fermat already knew. This would mean that the opposite of Fermat'c conjecture would be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One explanation for why $x^n+y^n=z^n$ should not hold for $xyz\neq 0$ and $n>2$ comes from the *abc-conjecture*, in terms of the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) of an integer. Basically it says that if $a+b=c$ and $a$ and $b$ are high powers of an integer, then $c$ cannot be a high power of an integer. For example, if $a=2^{13}$ and $b=5^{13}$, then
$$
a+b=2^{13}+5^{13}=1220711317=7\cdot 53\cdot 131\cdot 25117=c,
$$
and $c$ is far from being a high power.

Comment: Hmm, this should not have been a heuristic for people like Fermat himself, since the statement of the abc-conjecture is not so old, and I think also the whole idea is not so easy to grasp.

Comment: No, not for Fermat, but he OP also asks for an intuitive reason for the present time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the early pioneers have thought this way, but they might have.

If you write $ x^n - z^n = w $ and look at the prime-factorization of $w$ then you can use Fermat's little theorem to deduce that the exponents of the primefactors of $w$ grow only logarithmically with $n$. So it is very unlikely, that for larger $n$ we could have $w = p^n \cdot q^n \cdot \ldots \cdot u^n $ where $p \ldots u$ are the primefactors of $w$ - and this might have been very obvious to Fermat himself and also to Euler, who had analyzed this so-called "cyclotomic expression"s on the lhs and had generalized Fermat's little theorem to his "totient"-formula.

So ... this might have been a heuristic evidence for them pioneers ...

Comment: How exactly do we apply Fermat's little theorem here?

Comment: @Jack : by consideration of primefactors $p_k$ in $w$, and then we find, that their occurence in $x^n-z^n$ is periodic when increasing $n$ : for a primefactor $p$ the lhs $x^{p-1}-y^{p-1}$ is divisible by $p$ (this is little Fermat) and also $x^{(p-1)a}-y^{(p-1)a} \qquad a \in \mathbb N$ and so on. Using Euler's totient this is even more fluently expressible. Another keyword "LTE" or "Lifting the exponent" (google)

Comment: @Jack : I've made an essay focusing that primefactorization of the cyclotomic expression. The very last chapter might illustrate this more explicite:  http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For $n=3$ and $n=4$ it can be proved by infinite descent, as done by Euler and Fermat.

Lamé proposed a similar infinite descent approach when the cyclotomic integers have unique factorization. Alas, this does not always happen.

Comment: See http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com.br/2006/01/lams-proposed-proof.html and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953462/what-was-lames-proof.